# How to show open files with 'Accessed By' information

Tags: azure-files

How can I get information about which user has a specific file open on an Azure Files share?

so far I can only get a handlerId, but that doesn't tell me who has the file open. Is there a way to get that, like in a standard windows server share (computer management -> system tools -> Shared folders -> open files)

[image: windows server open files]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get 'Accessed By' information in Azure File Share by now. You can post a feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to progress this feature.